# How can I use Google Natural Processing API to extract emails from a text?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-natural-language

I want to extract emails from a text which I get from the business cards using Google Vision API. How can I do that using Natural Language API?
(I'm using Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having extracted text from images using Google Vision API (see https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text) it might be easier to use regex or some other text/pattern recognition algorithm.  Google Natural Language is more useful for sentiment analysis and categorizing content by theme as opposed to by text structures like email, physical address, phone number, things like that.